# java applet game jumping bug

Tags: java, applet

I'm currently making a java game and I just managed to make the character jump but it only works half the time.
Sometimes he will jump perfectly but other times he will get stuck in the air. I think its something to do with the gravity variable changing but I'm not sure Please can you have a look?

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class meatboy extends Applet implements KeyListener{
    public int x = 10, y = 300, gravity = 3;
    public int xs = 380, ys = 230 , jump_count, jump_move;
    double jumptime = 0;
    public boolean right, left, up, jump = true, start, grounded, grav = true;
    public void init(){
        setSize(800,400);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        addKeyListener(this);
        /////Movement//////
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask(){public void run(){

        if (start == true){
        if (right == true){
            x = x + 3;
        }if (left == true){
            x = x - 3;
        }if(up == true && jump == true){
            jump_count++;
            if (jump_count >= 100){
                jump_count = 0;
            }
            if (jump_count >= 0 && jump_count <= 25){
                //jump_move = 1;
                y = y - 5;
            }
            if (jump_count >= 25 && jump_count <= 50){
                //jump_move = 2;
                y = y - 5;
            }
            if (jump_count >= 50 && jump_count <= 75){
                //jump_move = 3;
                y = y - 5;
            }
            if (jump_count >= 75 && jump_count <= 100){
                //jump_move = 0;
                y = y - 5;
                jump = false;
            }
        }
        /////GRAVITY//////
        if (grav == true){y = y + gravity;}
        ///////Collision Dectection/////
        if(x > 790){//right of screen stop
            x = 10;
        }if(x < 10){// left stop
            x = 789;
        }if(y > 350){
            //y = y - 3;
            grav = false;
            jump = true;
        }else{grav = true;}
        ////////////End of collision///////////
        repaint();
        }}},10,10);


        ///////movement end////////
        }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        ////////CREATES MEATBOY///////////////
        if (start == false){
            x = 10; 
            y = 300;
            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString("MeatBoy 4K", 358, 180);
            g.drawString("Press Z to start!!!!", 350, 200);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(xs, ys, 16, 16);//meatboys body
            g.fillRect(xs + 16, ys + 6, 4, 4);//arm
            g.fillRect(xs - 4, ys + 6, 4, 4);//arm
            g.fillRect(xs, ys + 12, 4, 6);//leg
            g.fillRect(xs + 12, ys + 12, 4, 6);//leg
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(xs + 2, ys + 2, 5, 5);//eye
            g.fillRect(xs + 10, ys + 2, 5, 5);//eye

        }
        if (start == true){
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 16, 16);//meatboys body
        g.fillRect(x + 16, y + 6, 4, 4);//arm
        g.fillRect(x - 4, y + 6, 4, 4);//arm
        g.fillRect(x, y + 12, 4, 6);//leg
        g.fillRect(x + 12, y + 12, 4, 6);//leg
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(x + 2, y + 2, 5, 5);//eye
        g.fillRect(x + 10, y + 2, 5, 5);//eye
        ///////////END OF MEATBOY//////////////////
        ////////Creates Floor///////////////////
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 370, 800, 30);
        }
    }
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z){
            //right = true;
            start = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            //right = true;
            right = true;
        }if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            left = true;
        }if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            up = true;
        }if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            up = true;
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            //right = true;
            right = false;
        }if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            left = false;
        }if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            up = false;
        }if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            up = false;
        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Comment: You may want to accept some previous questions of yours and post comments in those threads thanking any volunteer who spent some of their own time and effort trying to help you. Why should anyone want to help you if are just going to ignore their help?

Comment: Something tells me that this is not a last question about jumping...

Answer (score 2):

Where does the player get stuck in the air?

If it's close to the ground, make sure that the y coordinate is right on the ground.

On this block of code:

```
}if(y > 350){
        //y = y - 3;
        grav = false;
        jump = true;
}else{grav = true;}
```

Add

```
}if(y > 350){
        //y = y - 3;
        grav = false;
        jump = true;

        //I'm on the ground all right
        y = 350;

}else{grav = true;}
```